# Does linux KASLR provides randomization of physical address on AARCH64?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using Linux kernel v4.14. I have built the kernel for my custom board which is AARCH64 architecture.
I have enabled `KASLR` with the `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y` flag.

However, each time I boot, I find that the physical address of the kernel code and data is the same.
(I checked this in `/proc/iomem`).

Does the KASLR not randomize the physical address of kernel code sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the `Kconfig` description for `RANDOMIZE_BASE` on Aarch64](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.7/source/arch/arm64/Kconfig#L1705):

> Randomizes the virtual address at which the kernel image is
> loaded, as a security feature that deters exploit attempts
> relying on knowledge of the location of kernel internals.
>
> It is the bootloader's job to provide entropy, by passing a
> random u64 value in `/chosen/kaslr-seed` at kernel entry.
>
> When booting via the UEFI stub, it will invoke the firmware's
> `EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL` implementation (if available) to supply entropy
> to the kernel proper. In addition, it will randomise the physical
> location of the kernel Image as well.

On its own, `RANDOMIZE_BASE` only randomizes the kernel image’s virtual address; to randomize the image’s physical address, the kernel needs help from the booloader (which is itself when it boots through [the UEFI stub](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.7/source/drivers/firmware/efi/libstub/arm64-stub.c#L49)).

Other architectures support randomizing the physical address too (*e.g.* x86).

Comment: The answer is correct for ARM. The source linux/arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr.c shows clearly that the virtual as well as the physical base is randomized on x86. In case someone got here by googling (the headline is misleading and should specify the arch)

Comment: Thanks, I’ve approved your edit on the question title and clarified that the answer is for Aarch64.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Google shows it as one of the first results if you search for "KASLR  Linux" and if you didn't pay close attention to the question, what I did initially ..., you would overlook it only applies to ARM. But now it is crystal clear :)